# prevhost.exe won't let me delete files

Tags: windows

I'm trying to delete some files (.pdf if it helps somehow) from explorer. When I check which app holds the handle to the file I find that its prevhost.exe. When I kill the process then I'm allowed to delete the files. What's prevhost.exe and anyone have an idea why it keeps handles on my files preventing me from deleting them?

Comment: It's used to display files in the explorer preview pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is Microsoft's Preview Handler Surrogate Host, and it allows Windows Explorer to generate the preview pane images. When it asks Adobe Reader to generate the preview, the file will be locked until it finishes.

Comment: It takes an awfully long time to do that though. So the problem may lie with Adobe Reader then?

Comment: @Jonn I think so, even the program itself is kinda slow.

Comment: @Jonn If you like, I could add how to remove Adobe Reader's preview

Comment: In light of this, the solution is much simpler than I'd thought. Just close the preview pane.

Comment: I'd just like to say this design for the preview pane is really stupid.